# Keep bash script running child processes until bash script end

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg

I would like to keep a command running (in this case ffmpeg) until a certain time.

The best way I know to do this is to wrap that command in a bash script that will keep checking to make sure it's running.

If it dies before that time, the script should restart it. I'm having trouble figuring out how do this. It seems like keeping a process running/restarting as needed until a term signal is a pretty common task.

I can't use a crontab entry because I have to wait until X outside source starts this process (and ultimately sends the terminate signal).

```
#!/bin/bash

#launch_ffmpeg()
#{
#   ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/$1/$2 -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/$1/$2 &
#   return $!
#}

on_die ()
{
    # kill all children
    pkill -KILL -P $$
}

trap 'on_die' TERM

# I think this is wrong
while :
    do
        ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/$1/$2 -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/$1/$2 &
        wait $!
        sleep 10
done
```

Comment: You aren't using `launch_ffmpeg` anywhere. You aren't checking for `ffmpeg` being running already anywhere.

Comment: use crontab for checking and restarting script.

Comment: I can't use a crontab because I don't know what the parameters to this script will be before hand and I don't know when it needs to start.

Comment: Have you tried a cron with flock in the bash script. This way the next cron will exit if there is an existing lock created by flock when the script is running...